# Convert WSE 3 client to WCF client

Tags: .net, wcf, wif

I have a WSE 3 client which consumes WSE 3 web-service + STS:

```
var stsService = new SecurityTokenServiceClient("https://stsurl");

var securityToken = stsService.requestSecurityToken("login", "password");

var st = new SecurityContextToken(securityToken);
transferObject.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(st);
```

So security token is just added to Token's collection and that we can call the service throught transferObject.

But now I need to implement a similar client using WCF. Here the code which I came to which unfortunately results in Validation error:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);

var client = new GeneratedClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://serviceurl"));

client.ClientCredentials.IssuedToken.LocalIssuerBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
client.ClientCredentials.IssuedToken.LocalIssuerAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://stsurl");
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "login";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

client.ChannelFactory.ConfigureChannelFactory();

var channel = client.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
var requestWrap = new Services.SomeMethodRequest();
requestWrap.ListShipments = request;
var response = channel.SomeMethod(requestWrap);
```

Is it a right way to consume STS authentication via WCF?

Answer (score 0):

This should put you on the right track

```
     EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress( OtherSTSAddress );
     UserNameWSTrustBinding binding = 
        new UserNameWSTrustBinding( SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential );

     WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory( binding, endpointAddress );
     factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
     factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = Password;
     factory.TrustVersion = System.ServiceModel.Security.TrustVersion.WSTrustFeb2005;

     WSTrustChannel channel = (WSTrustChannel)factory.CreateChannel();

     RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken(
         WSTrustFeb2005Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
         WSTrustFeb2005Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer );
     rst.AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress( YourStsAddress );

     SecurityToken token = channel.Issue( rst );
```